# input emoji in textview, some special characters showed?

Tags: ios, swift, textview, emoji, caret

I used a textview did a search function and have some requirements:

1）Add a question mark（?）in the end when user input text

2）The caret should before the question mark (?)

So I used a delegate of the textView. The code is:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.count == 0 {
        added = false
    }
    if !added {
        if textView.text.count > 0 && !textView.text.contains("?") {
            textView.text = textView.text + "?"
            textView.selectedRange = NSRange(location: textView.text.count - 1, length: 0)
            added = true
        }
    }
}
```

But when I input some emojis, the project crashed. The errors:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSURLComponents setPercentEncodedQuery:]:                                                   
invalid characters in percentEncodedQuery'
```

It looks like the parameters that contains some invalid characters. So I printed the text of the textView. When I inputed the emojis, the text like this:

[image]

Why would this happened? I used moya to make a request:

```
  func searchQuestion(_ text: String) {
    provider.rx.request(MultiTarget(QuestionAPI.searchQuestion(text: text))).asObservable()
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] response in
            do {
                let result = try response.filterSuccessfulStatusCodes()
                let json = try result.mapJSON() as! JsonObject
                if let model = SearchQuestionModel(JSON: json), let data = model.data {
                    self?.searchResult.onNext(data)
                }
            } catch { }
        }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
}
```

The request API is:

```
enum QuestionAPI {
    case searchQuestion(text: String)
}

extension QuestionAPI: TargetType {

var baseURL: URL {
    return URL(string: AppConfig.release)!
}

var path: String {
    switch self {
    case .searchQuestion:
         return "/api/client/questions/search"
    }
}

var method: Moya.Method {
    switch self {
    case .searchQuestion:
        return .get
    }
}

var sampleData: Data {
    switch self {
    case .searchQuestion,
        return "QuestionAPI".utf8Encoded
    }
}

var task: Task {
    switch self {
    case .searchQuestion(let text):
        return .requestParameters(parameters: ["title": text], encoding: URLEncoding.default)
    }
}

var headers: [String: String]? {
    return nil
}
}
```

Comment: Looks like your error it is not in the code posted. Are you trying to encode a url?  If so post the code related to your error.

Comment: Why you have added ? at end.

Comment: I used moya to make a request, the url encode is  URLEncoding.default. I will show more code  in question.

Comment: I used added  which is to make sure only add question mark when the text from empty to have.